# Unexpected Error: executing JavaScript/Reference error

Tags: xpages

I haven't made any changes to this database, and all of a sudden, I get an (500) error when loading various Xpages. On this one, when I switch to "Display the Xpage runtime error" on xpages tab of the database properties, it displays the errors below web.

If I remove the button that this Client side code is contained (it had worked perfectly to validate an Edit Box before), the error just moves to the next piece of JavaScript on the page and gives a similar error.

I've tried to "CLEAN" project. I've tried to Sign the entire database with the server id.

Any help would be much appreciated!

---

```
The runtime has encountered an unexpected error.
Error source

Page Name:/msr.xsp
Control Id: _id20


Exception

Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
Script interpreter error, line=3, col=8: [ReferenceError] 'XSP' not found
```

------the button control:

```
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
                                <xp:this.action>


                                    <xp:actionGroup>
                                        <xp:actionGroup>
                                            <xp:modifyField
                                                name="Status">
                                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:if     (document1.isNewNote()) {
"Submitted to Project Officer";
}
else if (document1.Status == "Submitted to Project Officer"){
    "Submitted to Supervisor";
}
else{
"Completed";
}}]]></xp:this.value>
                                            </xp:modifyField>
                                            <xp:saveDocument
                                                var="document1">
                                            </xp:saveDocument>

                                            <xp:changeDocumentMode
                                                mode="readOnly" var="document1">
                                            </xp:changeDocumentMode>
                                        </xp:actionGroup>

                                    </xp:actionGroup>
                                </xp:this.action>

                                <xp:this.script>
                                    <xp:executeClientScript>
                                        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:

if(XSP.getElementById("#{id:ProjectTitle}").value == ""){
        XSP.getElementById("#{id:ProjectTitle}").focus();
        XSP.getElementById("#{id:ProjectTitle}").style.backgroundColor = "pink";
        alert("Please enter a Project Title.");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        XSP.getElementById("#{id:ProjectTitle}").style.backgroundColor = "#ffe";
    }

///NOT sole source
if(XSP.getElementById("#{id:RT}").innerHTML == "MSR"){


if(XSP.getElementById("#{id:SoleSource}").checked == false){
    if(XSP.getElementById("#{id:SS_Name1}").value == ""){
        XSP.getElementById("#{id:SS_Name1}").focus();
        XSP.getElementById("#{id:SS_Name1}").style.backgroundColor = "pink";
        alert("Please fill in the Name of Suggested Source 1.");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        XSP.getElementById("#{id:SS_Name1}").style.backgroundColor = "#ffe";
    }
}
}

}]]></xp:this.script>
                                    </xp:executeClientScript>
                                </xp:this.script></xp:eventHandler>
                        </xp:button>
```

Comment: I would bounce the server before I did anything else.

Comment: Can you post the code for that particular control? The error message implies a failure on running SSJS, not CSJS.

Comment: We did a total restart of the server.
I added the code to the button control above...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `script` property of your `executeClientScript` action looks like it is being computed. The source should look something like this:

```
<xp:executeClientScript>
    <xp:this.script>
        <![CDATA[if(XSP.getElementById("#{id:ProjectTitle}").value == ""){...
]]></xp:this.script>
</xp:executeClientScript>
```

Instead, you have this:

```
<xp:executeClientScript>
    <xp:this.script>
        <![CDATA[#{javascript:if(XSP.getElementById("#{id:ProjectTitle}").value == ""){...
}]]></xp:this.script>
</xp:executeClientScript>
```

That syntax implies that, instead of simply entering client-side JavaScript to execute, you're running *server*-side JavaScript to *compute* what the client-side JavaScript should be. Server-side JavaScript does not define a global `XSP` object like client-side JavaScript does, which is why you're getting a `ReferenceError`.

Remove `#{javascript:` from the beginning of your `CDATA` block and the final `}` from the end, and your code will execute in the context you intended.

Comment: +1 This is common mistake: instead of writing CSJS code developer uses diamond to open SSJS editor...

Comment: Thank you. You have been very helpful!

Comment: @user2770131, if this answer met your needs, please use the "accept" feature to confirm for others who might be searching for the same information that this is a valid answer.

Comment: I have been looking for "accept". where is it?
Oh, I got it. It's the giant check mark...thanks